# matplotlib legend circle markers

Tags: matplotlib, geometry, legend

I'm making a legend for a scatter plot using a proxy artists (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist) and attempting to make circle-shaped markers.

This is my code:

```
legend([Circle((0,0), fc='g')], ["Green Circle"])
```

But when I plot it, the legend doesn't have a circle and instead displays a rectangle...

How do I get the legend to have circle markers?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If all you are looking for is a circular marker in the legend (as opposed to strictly using proxy artists), then I suggest trying something like:

```
line1 = Line2D([], [], color="white", marker='o', markerfacecolor="red")
line2 = Line2D([], [], color="white", marker='o', markerfacecolor="green")
line3 = Line2D([], [], color="white", marker='o', markersize=5,  markerfacecolor="slategray")
line4 = Line2D([], [], color="white", marker='o', markersize=10, markerfacecolor="slategray")
plt.legend((line1, line2, line3, line4), ('Thing 1', 'Thing 2', 'Thing 3', 'Thing 4'), numpoints=1, loc=1)
```

This shows you circles of different color and sizes, where the 2D line that is drawn is white (hence `color="white"`).  If you don't want the circles filled in, for example, set `markeredgecolor="green"` and `markerfacecolor="white"`.

**Further tweaks**

- If you don't have a white background, or if the line intersects with the grid in the background, `color="white"` will still show the line. `linewidth=0` will completely hide the line.
- Use the `handletextpad` keyword argument for `plt.legend` to reduce the space between the circle and the label. The value can also be negative, e.g. `handletextpad=-0.3`.
- If you are using `seaborn` palettes, you can set the individual marker face colors by indexing the palette. E.g. `markerfacecolor=sns.color_palette("cubehelix", 3)[0]`

Comment: Thanks - that works!  Just curious though, and idea why the other method doesn't work?

Comment: That's not exactly an answer to the question which specifically asks about how to use proxy artists e.g., matplotlib.patches.Circle to create legend keys irrespective of marker type.

Comment: No, OP asked "How do I get the legend to have circle markers?" and their original approach was to use proxy artists. The nice thing about this solution, as @pelson says in their answer, is that it's super easy to modify the markers: just use the table at: https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html

Comment: Any idea how I could tweak this to put multiple circles of increasing radius on a single legend line?

Comment: Do hide the line better use `linestyle='none'`.
To apply the same marker scale, take the square root. `np.sqrt(msize)`

Comment: This solution requires: `from matplotlib.lines import Line2D`

Answer (score 7):

@punkkat When adding patches (which Circle is) to be added to a legend, it is not the patch itself which is added, but a new Rectangle patch is created with exactly the same properties (color, hatching, alpha etc.) of the given patch. Hence, no matter the incoming shape, the result will be a square patch in the legend.

The simple solution, as given by @cosmosis, is to pass line instances to legend, which can support arbitrary markers, and since there is no limitation on the shape of a marker, there is no limitation on the shapes that you can pass to be put on the legend.